# What is the relation between the definition of learnability of Vapnik and Gold and learnability of neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, computational-learning-theory, comparison

Gold showed that a language can be learned only if it contains a finite set of sentences.

We know that deep neural networks can implement any function. Does this contradict the Gold's result?

What is the relation or difference between the definition of learnability of Vapnik and Gold and the definition of learnability of neural networks?

Comment: That's a problem about expressivity v.s. learnability.

Comment: This is an old question, but I suggest that you provide references where we can find the definitions that you were talking about.